# MyBatis call stored procedure using delete annotation

Tags: database, annotations, mybatis, commit, procedure

I have this Java method

```
@Override
public void callDelete_old_orders
        (int order_id) throws Exception {
    SqlSession sqlSession = getSqlSession();
    OrderMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(OrderMapper.class);
    
    mapper.callDelete_old_orders(order_id); 
}
```

Interface with MyBatis delete annotation

```
public interface OrderMapper {
    @Delete ("{CALL delete_old_orders(#{ order_id, mode = IN, jdbcType = INTEGER})} ")
    @Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
    public void callDelete_old_orders(int order_id);
}
```

And procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myself`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pizza_bro`.`delete_old_orders`(
    IN in_order_id INT)
begin
    delete from pizza_order where order_id <= in_order_id;
end
```

What could prevent records from being deleted from MariaDB table?

Comment: What happens if you write the DELETE statement directly in `@Delete` (and remove `@Options`)?

Comment: Strangely, @Delete("delete from pizza_order where order_id <= #{order_id}") is not working, either.

Comment: Assuming it does not throw any exception, it probably means either 1) there is no row matching the WHERE condition or 2) the transaction is rolled back for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I should have put commit statement after the mapper method call as follows:

```
@Override
public void callDelete_old_orders(int order_id) throws Exception {
    SqlSession sqlSession = getSqlSession();
    OrderMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(OrderMapper.class);

    mapper.callDelete_old_orders(order_id);
    ***sqlSession.commit();***
}
```